# R xgboost - how to use local data files?

Tags: r, xgboost, large-data

I have a large dataset, and I'm trying to use R's package `xgboost` to perform a regression on it.

The function `xgboost` says that the argument `data` can be a *local data file*, from which I understand it should be the name of the file to be used. There are however no further specifications about it, so my question is how exactly should be this file.

I've tried

```
random=matrix(rnorm(15),5,3)
colnames(random)=c("first","second","label")
write.csv(random,"random.csv")
bst <- xgboost(data = "random.csv", 
               nthread = 7, 
               nround = 3,
               objective="reg:linear",
               verbose=FALSE)
```

but that returns

```
6x0 matrix with 0 entries is loaded from random.csv
Error in xgb.iter.update(bst$handle, dtrain, i - 1, obj) : 
NumCol:need column access
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xgboost` local data file input does not support `csv`. Quoting from this [link](http://blog.nycdatascience.com/uncategorized/xgboost-introduction/)

> Currently XGBoost supports local data files in the libsvm format. - See more at: http://blog.nycdatascience.com/uncategorized/xgboost-introduction/#sthash.bmlHst0T.dpuf

See [this Cross Validated Question/Answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61328/libsvm-data-format) for more information on what the libsvm format is.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I am not yet allowed to comment, and this is a bit naive for a proper answer but just to be sure:
- Have you made sure that `R` is in the right folder? Try `getwd()` to check which working directory you are located and `setwd()` to change it.

I will delete my answer later since I will that it is incomplete,

greetings,

Daniel